# Matching multiline text between specific strings with an optional end

Tags: regex, conditional-statements

I have problem writing a conditional regex. I need to find multiline text with an optional end. Usually it is the "normal end", sometimes I have this additional suffix.

Could some one please support me with this problem.

Here is my example:

```
Start of Text
 some thing in between
 some thing in between
 some thing in between
Normal end of text
Optional suffix


^(?:Start)[\d\w\s]*?(?(?=Optional.*)Optional.*|Normal.*)
```

It only matches until "Normal end of text"
Even though, the "Optional" is present. What I understood from contional regex, it should find "Optional" and though match "Optional"

Thank you so much.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html…?

Comment: Please show examples of text that matches, and text that does not match.

Comment: I updated the initial request

Comment: Something like `^(Start)((?s:.*?))(Normal.*)(\s*Optional.*)?`? https://regex101.com/r/UnFP3H/1

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew
that worked. I will investigate the differences :-)

Comment: I posted the answer with explanation to help you  with the investigatation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(Start)((?s:.*?))(Normal.*)(\s*Optional.*)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UnFP3H/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(Start)` - Group 1: `Start`
- `((?s:.*?))` - Group 2: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(Normal.*)` - Group 3: `Normal` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(\s*Optional.*)?` - an optional Group 4 matching zero or more whitespaces, `Optional` and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible.